# Usemin not removing block statements

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt to build a dist and for some reason usemin WON'T remove the
build statements. I'm not getting any errors during the build and some statements get removed and others don't. The files get minified, but they don't get linked.

Example dist code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script src="scripts/2b96018a.cv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Original:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/cv.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need that bower:css comment? Try removing it.

Comment: It would be good to see your grunt config and the build's output.

Comment: I encountered this error when I had mixed LF and CRLF terminators in the same file. Converting the file to UNIX EOL (LF) terminators fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the exact same problem. I noticed that removing the bower/endbower statments made it work, but you loose the benefit of bower-install. I'm still working on it

Comment: I'm seeing this, too--when I remove the bower tags, it works.  Has a bug been filed with usemin?  This is driving me crazy.